# Mac OSX crashed and now global PATH settings seem to be incorrect

Tags: macos, crash, eclipse, path, dock

I had to hard power off my mac when it froze on the login screen after a sleep resume.

After the reset it seems like any application that uses the system environment PATH to launch other processes doesn't work.

For example, if I launch eclipse using the GUI / Dock / Finder I get:

> A Java Runtime Environment (JRE) or Java Development Kit (JDK) must be
>   available in order to run Eclipse.

If I launch using the command line, eclipse opens just fine.

Similarly, if I run Qt Creator and try to use the git from within Qt Creator the applications complains that it cannot locate git.

I can run git with no problems from the command line.

It seems like the path setting for the OSX GUI have been destroyed/corrupted as all of this worked perfectly before the crash.

Any ideas?

Running OSX 10.8.3